# when using SQL GROUP BY, one 'group' may have several different value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which have 2 columns: test_name(text), created_at(date) .

when I use this piece of code:

```
SELECT test_name, MONTH(created_at) AS Month, COUNT(created_at) AS Num_Completed_Tests
FROM complete_tests
GROUP BY Month;
```

My question is: each month have several different test_name, but this code did not lead to an error.

**add some content**

when I execute this code, i got:

```
test_name   Month   Num_Completed_Tests
Delayed Cup Game    1   11068
Yawn Warm-up    2   9122
Yawn Warm-up    3
```

if i add 'WHERE MONTH(created_at)=1' into the code, I got 'Delayed Cup Game' in the first line;

if i add 'WHERE MONTH(created_at)=2' into the code, I got 'Yawn Warm-up' in the first line;

Seems like the system always select test_name of the  FIRST line , I don't know if this is a MySQL rule.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL - any self-respecting DBMS would reject it). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using

Comment: I think if it doesn't lead to an error that's MySql.

Comment: Is the column `Month` a primary key by any chance? Some engines let you select other columns outside the group by if the group by contains a PK column. Full working example might help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this  shuold happen for mysql version before 5.7, but most recent version should raise an error .. fro the most recent versions this behavior is manage by SQL_MODE setting ..

anyway for the version of mysql that admit this the result for the column not involved in aggreagtion function and not mentioned  group by 
is unpredictable  (return the casual first value retrived)

You should manage this using a (fake) aggregated function if the result for this column is not important  ..

```
SELECT min(test_name)
  , MONTH(created_at) AS Month
  , COUNT(created_at) AS Num_Completed_Tests
FROM complete_tests
GROUP BY Month;
```

or adding the column in group by if you need  a detailed  result

```
SELECT test_name
  , MONTH(created_at) AS Month
  , COUNT(created_at) AS Num_Completed_Tests
FROM complete_tests
GROUP BY test_name, Month;
```